# Why south of Japan has a zone with winds facing each other?

Tags: meteorology, oceanography, wind

This is an image of the wind in est Asia, south of Japan.
How do you explain this zone I circled in pink, where winds from north and south face each other? Thanks

[image]

Comment: @maalis that is just an area of temporary convergence

Comment: what research have you done before asking this question?,please provide a source for any pictures or text you use from other sites.the picture used here in your question is from nullschool.net

Comment: It's called a "front".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [synopic weather chart](https://www.weathercharts.org/japan-mslp.htm), the zone you highlighted corresponds with a [stationary front](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_front) just to the east of Taiwan.

[image]